# react view not re-rendering on data change

Tags: reactjs

I was wondering how I could get react to know that the db value for count has changed and update the view accordingly. Do I have to have a function in the class that the DB calls to manually force the change in state or prop or is there a way to get react to poll for the data in some way or know when it changes?

```
import React from 'react';
import { DB } from '../../backend/db';


export default class Home extends React.Component {

testCount() {
    DB.testCount();
}

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            Hello World!
            <button onClick={this.testCount}>
                Click me!
            </button>
            <CountView count={DB.getCount()}></CountView>
        </div>
    );
}
}

class CountView extends React.Component {
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      count: DB.getCount()
    }
}

render() {
    return (
        <div>state:{this.state.count} props:{this.props.count}</div>
    );
}
}
```

Comment: you can use `shouldComponentUpdate` function to change the state

Comment: use a combination of `Redux` and `componentWillReceiveProps`

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to take a polling based approach as mentioned in your question, you could achieve that by means of the following:

```
export default class Home extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    // Set default count to be displayed prior to polling
    this.state = {
      count : 0
    }
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {

    // When component is about to unmount, stop polling
    this.polling = undefined
  }

  componentDidMount() {

    // Flag polling as running
    this.polling = true

    // Start polling
    this.poll()
  }

  // Polling iteration method
  poll() {

    setTimeout(() => {

      // If component unmounted, prevent further polling
      if(!this.polling) {
        return
      }

      // Updates state causing re-render
      this.setState({ count : DB.getCount() })

      // Run next polling iteration
      this.poll();

    }, 2000) // Polling interval
  }

  render() {
      return (
          <div>
              Hello World!
              <button onClick={this.testCount}>
                  Click me!
              </button>
              { /* Update render method to display count from state */}
              <CountView count={ this.state.count }></CountView>
          </div>
      );
  }
}
```

Comment: Really do we have componentDidUnMount() method in React? So far I know only componentWillUnMount()

Answer (score 0):

By default, when your component’s state or props change, your component will re-render. If your render() method depends on some other data, you can tell React that the component needs re-rendering by calling forceUpdate().

React doc: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#forceupdate

```
import React from 'react';
import { DB } from '../../backend/db';

export default class Home extends React.Component {
  testCount() {
    DB.testCount();
    this.forceUpdate();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
          Hello World!
          <button onClick={() => this.testCount()}>
            Click me!
          </button>
          <CountView count={DB.getCount()} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

...
```